# Inserting table from one table to another, and adding values are specified

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to insert value in a table, extracted from another table, but some values are specified by me, and therefore not from another table.

```
    INSERT INTO Person (age)
    SELECT age FROM AnotherPerson;
```

Now let's pretend that I want to add another data in another column in the person table, and this data is not extracted from the other table. So what I'm thinking, is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Person (age, name)
VALUES (SELECT age FROM AnotherPerson, 'Peter');
```

The above code is just an example I came up with, so I'm can stay with the relevant aspect.

I was thinking that I could insert the data separately, which would work, since this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Person (age, name)
VALUES (SELECT age FROM AnotherPerson, 'Peter');
```

doesn't work.

But what if all the ecolumns of the Person table must be not null? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Person (age, name)
SELECT age, 'Peter' FROM AnotherPerson
```

Comment: You type faster than the rest of us!

Comment: I did not have to read the question. I say the title and started typing :)